# Repeat mode for SVG displacement filter

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to apply a continuous 'flowing' turbulence on an image through SVG filter. This is the svg (Edited after a suggestion in the comments):

```
<svg>

    <filter id="filter" >
        
        <feTurbulence 
        id="turb" 
        type="turbulence" 
        baseFrequency="0.5 0" 
        numOctaves="3"  
        stitchTiles="noStitch" 
        result="turbulence"/>

        <!-- Below code inserted from stackoverflow response -->
        <feColorMatrix in="turbulence" type="hueRotate" values="0" result="cloud">
            <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </feColorMatrix>

        <feDisplacementMap 
        id="disp" 
        in="SourceGraphic" 
        in2="cloud" 
        xChannelSelector="R" 
        yChannelSelector="G" 
        scale="50" 
        result="displacementMap"/>

    </filter>

</svg>
```

Applying it with

```
img{
width: 100%;    
filter: url(#filter);
}
```

And this is how I am updating it with JS

```
let turb = document.getElementById('turb');
turb.setAttribute('baseFrequency', `0 ${current.toFixed(6)}`)
```

Here `current` is a self-incrementing value in my `requestAnimationFrame` function, but it keeps piling up the displacement texture over the image.

Take a look:
[image]

I want it to stick to a max baseFrequency value and then flow smoothly on the chosen axis like `Pixi.js` allows in its **Displacement Filter** when it is put to **repeat mode**. Any idea?

Comment: don't animate baseFrequency, add a feColorMatrix with a hueRotate from 0 to 360 degrees beteween the turbulence and the displacement and you'll get a continuous and interrupt free displacement animation. https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/AZqQqB

Comment: @MichaelMullany thanks for your answer, but it's not working for me, I have added this between them:
`<feColorMatrix in="turbulence" type="hueRotate" values="0" result="cloud">
                <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </feColorMatrix>`
And in the `feDisplacementMap`, `in2="cloud"`. Not working

Comment: You forgot to set your channel selectors in your feDisplacementMap:  xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"

Comment: @MichaelMullany thanks it works!! Please share this as an answer so that I choose it as selected :D